# Writing to a file on a remote linux machine

Tags: shell, ssh

I need to connect to a remote linux machine via ssh, take the system information and write it to a file on the remote linux machine.

I've tried something like this:

```
ssh username@remoteip "cat /etc/os-release; hostname" > result.txt
```

It really takes information about the remote system, but writes it to a local file. How can I write this information to a remote file?

Comment: run the redirection remotely instead of locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls use this, put the file path as remote PC path:

```
ssh username@remoteip "(cat /etc/os-release; hostname) > /home/remotePC/path/remote_result.txt"
```

Comment: It's more efficient (avoids subshell creation) to write it as `{ cat /etc/os-release; hostname; } >/home/...` with `{ ...; }` instead of `( ... )`